# processing 'multipart/form-data' in hapi3.2.8 getting request.pipe error

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, hapi.js

I am trying to process 'multipart/form-data' data in Hapi using multiparty module.
[Followed server.js code similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823379/how-to-upload-files-using-nodejs-and-hapi)

I am trying to processing 'multipart/form-data' in hapi3.2.8 getting request.pipe error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably over-complicating things.  Multiparty is 'baked in' to Hapi so you don't need to use it as a separate module (which is why I think it doesn't expose request.pipe).

Take a look at the examples [here](https://github.com/paullang/hapi-post-example).