# How to upload images in Hapi.Js via multipart request?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, hapi.js

How to make an API in node.js using hapi and accept multipart request from client? I found [pez](https://github.com/hapijs/pez), but I don't really know what it is and know how it works since it doesn't really provide any description or document.

I've made similar service in Express using multer [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), or perhaps is it the same thing as pez?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files using nodejs and HAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823379/how-to-upload-files-using-nodejs-and-hapi)

Comment: @GabrielBleu i dont think so, i've read that question and my question is how to upload using multipart. and to backup my question pez didnt provide any documentation or any description on how to use it.

Comment: Did you read the top voted answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to make a little library to parse multipart request in javascript generally, the code is available [here](https://github.com/nooballday/js-multipart-parser).

Answer (score 0):

```
let fs = require('fs');
let Hapi = require('hapi');

letserver = Hapi.createServer('localhost', Number(process.argv[2] || 8080));

server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/submit',
    config: {

        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },

        handler: function (request, reply) {
            let data = request.payload;
            if (data.file) {
                let name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                let path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
                let file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

                file.on('error', function (err) { 
                    console.error(err) 
                });

                data.file.pipe(file);

                data.file.on('end', function (err) { 
                    let ret = {
                        filename: data.file.hapi.filename,
                        headers: data.file.hapi.headers
                    }
                    reply(JSON.stringify(ret));
                })
            }

        }
    }
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
});
```

this code works for multipart request,you need to mention type of the payload allowed.